# md-select error message trigger in angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a `md-select` and a corresponding submit button that I use to call a web-service and pass data from `md-select` (I am not using any forms here):

```
<div class="col-8">
    <md-select placeholder="Select User" class="custom-select" id="user" name="user" [(ngModel)]="user" floatPlaceholder="never">
        <md-option *ngFor="let user of users| keys" [value]="user.key">{{user.value}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
<div class="col-2 mb-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn blue-btn" (click)="ws(user)">View Details</button>
</div>
```

Upon submit and before calling web-service, I want to check whether any option has been selected and display an error message (angular material style) in case none is.
The Angular documentation mentions an `errorStateMatcher` for `mdInput` but none for `md-select`.

Answer (score 1):

make use of **ngModelChange**

```
<md-select placeholder="Select User" class="custom-select" id="user" name="user" [(ngModel)]="user" floatPlaceholder="never" (ngModelChange)="changeSelected($event)">
        <md-option *ngFor="let user of users| keys" [value]="user.key">{{user.value}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
```

**Component**

```
changeSelected(event) {
  this.user = event.user;
}
```

Comment: My priority is generating error angular material style in the UI

Comment: @HBK they you have to make use of forms [this](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive) might help

Answer (score 0):

The best way, IMO, is to use reactive forms :

```
myForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
        user: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}

submitMethod() {
    if (this.myForm.valid) {/* ... */}
}

// HTML
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitMethod" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <select formControlName="user" ...>
</form>
```